# How I put a global state array of objects inside local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, global-state

I am working on an ecommerce website. I create a global state using the library in the react-hooks-global-state (the link below). I want the array to save when I refresh or redirect the page. However, when I store it in local storage I get an infinite loop.

library: https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-global-state

**_**___

I tried this method with use effect, now putting the array in local storage works, but getting it out causes the infinite loop:

state:

```
import { createGlobalState } from "react-hooks-global-state";

const { setGlobalState, useGlobalState } = createGlobalState({
  cartItems: [],
});
export { useGlobalState, setGlobalState };
```

code:

```
const [cartItemslit] = useGlobalState("cartItems");

useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("literalcartting");
    if (data !== null) {
      setGlobalState("cartItems", JSON.parse(data));
    }
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      "literalcartting",
      JSON.stringify(cartItemslit)
    );
  }, cartItemslit);
```

Comment: Be careful with useEffect, the second arugement should be an array.
So the first useEffect should be an empty array [] as you want to trigger only one time but the second useEffect should be [cartItemsLit]

Comment: i dont really understand can you show me?

Comment: see the response of Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code have the problem of infinite rendering, there is no dependency array in both of the `useEffect` hooks,

Try this code,

```
const [list, setCartItems] = useGlobalState("cartItems");

useEffect(() => {
  const data = window.localStorage.getItem("literalcartting");
  if (data !== null) {
    setCartItems(JSON.parse(data));
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem(
    "literalcartting",
    JSON.stringify(list)
  );
}, [list]);
```

In the first `useEffect` I have added an empty dependency array `[]` so that this `useEffect` hook is renderd only one time.

In the second one I have added `[list]` as a dependency array so the this `useEffect` hook only works only when there is some change in the `list`.

Edit - Persisting data in localStorage

Add this useEffect hook after the two hooks,

```
 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      window.localStorage.setItem("literalcartting", JSON.stringify(list));
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: infinite loop is gone, but it does not save the array!

Answer (score 0):

this is everything so far:

```
const [list, setCartItems] = useGlobalState("cartItems");

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("literalcartting");
    if (data !== null) {
      setCartItems(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("literalcartting", JSON.stringify(list));
  }, [list]);
 

  const onAdd = (product) => {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "420px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.filter = "blur(10px)";
    const exist = list.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist) {
      setGlobalState(
        "cartItems",
        list.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
        )
      );
    
    } else {
      setGlobalState("cartItems", [...list, { ...product, qty: 1 }]);
    }
  };
  const onRemove = (product) => {
    const exist = list.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist.qty === 1) {
      setGlobalState(
        "cartItems",
        list.filter((x) => x.id !== product.id)
      );
    } else {
      setGlobalState(
        "cartItems",
        list.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty - 1 } : x
        )
      );
```

the infinite loop is gone, but still state is not saved when I refresh. I checked the local storage and indeed the array saved gets wiped out the moment I refresh the page. Any fix?
And thank you a lot for the help + thought I might add the functions where I alter the array.

Comment: Are you getting everything all right before refreshing? Means is your localStorage is getting the required data?

Comment: Yes everything is all right before refreshing

Comment: Check the latest edit if that is working for you.